# Spring cloud stream: Two different Kafkas in same app

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to use two different Kafka in the same app.

When I have only one Kafka my application.yml is:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
       kafka:
         binder:
           brokers: kafka_broker01
           zkNodes: kafka_broker01
           headers: type

       binders:
         some-binder:
           type: kafka
           inheritEnviroment: true
```

But I don't know what to do in case I have some other Kafka server to reference in bindings:

```
  kafka:
    binder:
      brokers: other_kafka_broker01
      zkNodes: other_kafka_broker01
      headers: type
```

How do I have to rearrange the properties?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is too general so I'd suggest to start by looking at [Multibinder samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/multibinder-samples) which include several variations including Kafka. There is more information and details on multiple binder support in [reference manual](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#multiple-binders).

Comment: The trick was here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/multibinder-samples/multibinder-two-kafka-clusters/src/main/resources/application.yml